# ValidationError in web3py

Tags: web3py

```
uniswap_v3_quoter_contract.functions.quoteExactInputSingle(wbtc_token, weth_token, web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'), 3000, 0).call()
```

raise error

```
ValidationError: 
Could not identify the intended function with name `quoteExactInputSingle`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `quoteExactInputSingle`: ['quoteExactInputSingle(address,address,uint24,uint256,uint160)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

I've tried many times but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because you submit string instead of address format.
if you are using web3 python (https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.main.html#addresses) you can use is_checksum_address to verify the format or to_checksum_address to change your string to address format.